# empty search criteria message does not function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

the below java script is to prompt pop up message,

```js
function TrimString(sInString) {
    sInString = sInString.replace(/^\s+/g, ""); // strip leading
    return sInString.replace(/\s+$/g, ""); // strip trailing
}
function ValidateEmptyCriteria(form) {

    var bolAllEmpty = true;`enter code here`
    for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
        // alert(i);
        //alert(form.elements[i].type); 
        if (form.elements[i].type == 'text') {
            if (TrimString(form.elements[i].value) != "") {
                bolAllEmpty = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (form.elements[i].type == 'select-one') {
            if (form.elements[i].selectedIndex > 0) {
                bolAllEmpty = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (form.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            if ((form.elements[i].checked) == true) {
                bolAllEmpty = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        
    }

    if (bolAllEmpty) {
        return ConfirmEmptyCriteriaSearch();
    }
    else return (true);
}

function ConfirmEmptyCriteriaSearch() {
    var agree = confirm("No search string is entered. Click [0K] to show all records.");

    if (agree)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function ValidateEmptyCriteriaExcludeDate(form) {
    var bolAllEmpty = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
        // alert(i);
        //alert(form.elements[i].type); 
        if (form.elements[i].type == 'text') {
            if (TrimString(form.elements[i].value) != "" && form.elements[i].id != 'txtFromDate' && form.elements[i].id != 'txtToDate') {
                bolAllEmpty = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (form.elements[i].type == 'select-one') {
            if (form.elements[i].selectedIndex > 0) {
                bolAllEmpty = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (bolAllEmpty) {
        return ConfirmEmptyCriteriaSearch();
    }
    else return (true);
}
```

- then I used the below code to call the function to pages.

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Control/ValidateEmptyCriteria.js")%>"></script>
```

the below is the button code,

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                                <tr class="clsTBRow" style="height: 8px;">
                                                                    <td style="width: 10px;" />
                                                                    <td style="width: 150px;" />
                                                                    <td />
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr class="clsTBRow">
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        &nbsp;
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        Card Type Name :
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCardTypeName" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Width="200px" />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr class="clsTBRow">
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        &nbsp;
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        Description :
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Width="200px" MaxLength="100" />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr class="clsTBRow" style="height: 50px; vertical-align: middle;">
                                                                    <td colspan="2">
                                                                        &nbsp;
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <span id="spanCmdSubmit" runat="server">
                                                                            <asp:Button ID="CmdSubmit" runat="server" Text="Search" />&nbsp;</span> <span id="spanCmdReset"
                                                                                runat="server">
                                                                                <asp:Button ID="CmdReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" /></span>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
```

- The problem is it does not work. any help I can get on this issue pls?
- the thing i need is when my textbox is empty and i clicked search, then it should prompt out the pop up message which i state in the java script.

Comment: Where is your search button? paste code

Comment: The code you have supplied is not particularly useful, it is spread across multiple code snippets and the button code is asp.net not HTML. Have a look at the HTML that your page produces. Reduce the HTML and JavaScript down to the minimum you need to reproduce the problem. And then see if you can create a simple jsfiddle or code snippet based on that.

Comment: Take a look at [Validator Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/bwd43d0x.aspx). These are build-in the dot.net framework itself and will save you a lot of JavaScript coding.